# What is the difference between append and addObject + Compare two date

Tags: ios, swift, string, append, nsdate

I am little bit confuse about, what is the difference between append and addObject.

I am using both in my code but confuse what is the difference between them.

**addObject**

```
self.dateArrayServer.addObject(date as! String)
```

**append**

```
dateArrayCalendar.append(dateFormatatter.stringFromDate(dateStart))
```

**And Second problem is**

Hi,
 I am try to compare two date-

dateArrayForCompare, is the date which i get from NSDate and, dateArrayServer, is the date which i get from json response.

```
 var dateArrayServer = NSMutableArray()
 var dateArrayCalendar = NSMutableArray()
 var dateArrayForCompare = NSMutableArray()



let dateHomework:NSArray = allAsign.valueForKey("date") as! NSArray
 let homeWork = allAsign.valueForKey("assignmenttype") as! NSArray       

for date in dateHomework{
self.dateArrayServer.addObject(date as! String)
         }


let sys_date = NSDate()
                        print("System Date: \(sys_date)")
                        let df = NSDateFormatter()
                        df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                        let currentDate = df.stringFromDate(sys_date)
                        print("String Date: \(currentDate)")

                        for dt in 0...self.dateArrayServer.count-1
                        {
                            if(self.dateArrayServer.objectAtIndex(dt) .isEqualToString("\(self.dateArrayForCompare)"))
                            {
                                print("Assignment on date: \(self.dateArrayServer.objectAtIndex(dt)) are:\n\(allAsign.objectAtIndex(dt))")
                            }else
                            {
                                print("\(self.dateArrayServer.objectAtIndex(dt)) doesn't match with \(self.dateArrayForCompare) ")
                            }
                        }
```

But get this result-

[image]

Comment: What data type is `dateArrayCalendar`?

Comment: is this not the difference between using an NSMutableArray and a swift array?

Comment: **var dateArrayCalendar = [String]()**

Comment: **var dateArrayServer = NSMutableArray()**

Comment: well there you have it, thats the difference... :P functionally both methods do the same thing, the name is different because they are different types of arrays

Comment: Yes one is old array type(NS) and another is Swift array type `[String]`

Answer (score 4):

not a major different but i think i can explain it.
in swift two data type declare first "let" and "var" this two type accept all type of data .
but whenever you add array in "var" but not declare this is NSArray  or NSMutableArray then you put any object on last position in it then you use append.
appen is like "+=" operator so it add that value on last position

```
var Array = ["1","2"]
Array.append(["3"])

//Result :- "1","2","3"
```

But you Declare as

```
NSMutableArray or NSArray
```

then you must use addObject like

```
var Array = NSMutableArray()
Array.addObject("1")
Array.addObject("2")
Array.addObject("3")

//Result :- "1","2","3"
```

And other different

1. append is get that **value** and put on last index .
2. addObject is get that **Object** and put on last index

and value and object have different meaning.

Comment: The code snippets are for JS. Use the general code blocks for other languages

Answer (score 0):

`Add(anObject: Any)` on a `NSMutableArray` is equal to `Append(element: Element)` on an `array`,

Append in documentation:

```
 Adds a new element at the end of the array.

     Use this method to append a single element to the end of a mutable array.

         var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
         numbers.append(100)
         print(numbers)
         // Prints "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100]"

     Because arrays increase their allocated capacity using an exponential
     strategy, appending a single element to an array is an O(1) operation
     when averaged over many calls to the `append(_:)` method. When an array
     has additional capacity and is not sharing its storage with another
     instance, appending an element is O(1). When an array needs to
     reallocate storage before appending or its storage is shared with
     another copy, appending is O(*n*), where *n* is the length of the array.

     - Parameter newElement: The element to append to the array.

     - Complexity: Amortized O(1) over many additions. If the array uses a
       bridged `NSArray` instance as its storage, the efficiency is
       unspecified.
```

Add object in documentation:

```
The object to add to the end of the array’s content. This value must not be nil.
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between append and addObject

**Append** : It appends your array with multiple items like for exa

```
var cityArray: String[] = ["Portland","San Francisco","Cupertino","Seattle"]
cityArray.append(["Vancouver", "Los Angeles", "Eugene"])
```

In append you can add multiple elements at a time

there is a property appendContentsof("collectiontype or sequencetype element") with it you can add multiple elements

**AddObject** : It add one object at a time at the end of array

but notice that NSArray and NSMutableArray doesn't have property **append** keyword, So you can not use append in this type of array

Answer (score 0):

**Mainly difference between append and addobject with example.**

You already know the difference between **NSArray** and **NSMutableArray**. NSArray its a fixed array and NSMutablearray is the dynamic Array means you can increase the size of this Array in Run time so its depend on your requirement which one is the best. Because if you are using the NSArray means you don't have required to increase the value in run time then you can use NSArray with **append** and in Run time You want to increase the value then you can use NSMutablearray and **addobject:**.

**NSArray** when you are using the Array then you can use append object like this.

```
var str1:String = "John"
var str2:String = "Bob"
var myArray = ["Steve", "Bill", "Linus", "Bret"]
myArray.append(str1)
myArray.append(str2)
```

**NSMutableArray** when you are using the NSMutableArray then you can use addobject

```
var myArray1 : NSMutableArray = ["Hello"]
myArray1.addObject(str1)
```